# Security and Microsoft Teams / Microsoft OneDrive / Share Point Online?

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-onedrive, microsoft-sharepoint-online

As a user of these products, how concerned do I have to be about who can see what I place in the system?

I don't know who pays the bill and thus has access to everything in there, and I don't know where the computers are that are storing the data, if it's encrypted etc...

If I was using a similar system in Linux I would be able to encrypt it myself no mater where it is stored, but the whole thing here is from Windows and it's all a little ambiguous.

Comment: Is this provided by your employer?

Comment: This seems like something you would want to address with your organization. They "should" have policy and/or someone who would be able to address these questions. If it's private then you'll have to dig into the documentation, though Microsoft usually has good documentation. For instance: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/secure-sharepoint-online-sites-and-files

Comment: I was interested because I have not in the past worked with systems where a company does the security for you in this way.